# Transfer private projects to an “organization” account?

Tags: git, gitlab

We are a group of people. We will develop a project in our own private space, if the changes are done, we have to add the repository in the organization account. What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project settings. Then scroll down to `Transfer project`. Here select as `Namespace` your organization.